# Perl preventing same data INSERT to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a array of hash of hash which I am differencing and inserting it accordingly to a single table LOCATION such that it fits to the column name. The code is as follows:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:saferoute";
my $username = "root";
my $password = "password";

my %attr = (PrintError=>0,RaiseError=>1);
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr);

while (my ($year, $year_ref) = each(%$stat) ){
    while (my ($state, $state_ref) = each(%$year_ref) ){
            while (my ($city, $city_ref) = each(%$state_ref) ){
                    foreach my $crime_ref (@$city_ref){
                            while (my ($crime, $crime_stat) = each (%$crime_ref) ){
                                    my $sql = qq|INSERT INTO LOCATION (COUNTRY, STATE, DISTRICT, CITY, LOCALITY_NAME, PIN_CODE, SAFETY_RANKING) VALUES ('IN', '$state', '$city', '$city', 'city', '11111', 1)|;
                                    my $stmt = $dbh->do($sql);
                    }
                    }
            }
    }
}
$dbh->disconnect();
```

The code runs fine and inserts the data accordingly. but whenever I run the above script it populates the data. For example the first time I run it it creates 1000 rows, next time it creates 2000 rows and so on. Any suggestion regarding how can I prevent it such that the same type of data is not inserted in individual row. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a conditional statement
2. pull your already generated data from sql
3. check to see if it equals what your inserting
4. if data != data insert

There are some modules you might be interested in as well
Class::DBI, Rose::DB, DBIx::Class

look through these ... might make life easier on ya... Good Luck
[Perl ORM database module comparison](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=700283)